# Automated unit testing for Android / Ant

Tags: android, testing, ant, junit

I have an Android project and JUnit tests in my code.

I wanted to know if there is an **ant task** to run some tests.

In fact, I have several classic tests which are run using JUnit to test several methods, and some tests that need an android emulator or at least need to be run on an android device.

As I didn't find any documentation, I wanted to know if it's possible to do that kind of thing.

Like

> junit-android dir="."...

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Just to be clear because I've search on the web and didn't find many things, so hope you can help.

I have an Android project that contains NO activities.

Actual **build.xml** file:

1. I compile java source code
2. It generates me a .jar file.
3. I need to run some tests defined in my *project/tests/* folder, using
   the previous generated library. Thoses tests need to be runned on an
       emulator device using ANT build file, whithout being dependent of
       Eclipse.

Project:

> - src (java source code)
> - gen
> - bin
> - res
> - tests (Android test project)
> - AndroidManifest.xml
> - build.xml
> - ...

The test project generated is containing a build.xml that has been automatically generated using *android update command*. Sadly, there is no task "run-tests". And how do I specify that I would like to use my library for those tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you need to create and run android test projects from the command line, provided by Google itself ;-)
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html

The [command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#AMSyntax) you need is something like:

```
adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>
```

To call that from Ant, use the `<run-tests/>` task, described [here.](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsAnt)

Answer (score 1):

Create a target in your build.xml like this

```
<target name="run-tests">
    <test-junit includedTests="pathToPackageContainingTests}/*.class" />
</target>
```

Then you can simply do this

```
ant clean release run-tests
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will work like that.
It just says "failed to create task or type test-junit
Cause: The name is undefined." Do I need a library ?